# Folder of Java Run Time Environment change with updates?

Tags: directory, java

Does the JRE folder change when updates are made to it?

I am expecting this file to be in this folder:

```
C:\program files\java\jre1.5.0_01\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

Does the name of this folder change when updates to the JRE are downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

After Java 6.something, all updates are applied to the same folder, usually `%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre6` - so you don't get multiple JVMs installed by default like you did before (one for `1.5.0_01`, one for `1.5.X`, etc).

What are you trying to do though? Do you really need to access that `.dll` using an absolute path? Have you tried using `%Java_Home%`?

Comment: Yes, unforunately I do. It is a third-party component that requires it. I am finding that the JRE redistributable starts out at 1.5.0_01 but ends up at about 0_15 after updates which makes it impossible to maintain a link to this folder.

Comment: What is %Java_Home%? Is that usually set when JRE is installed?

Comment: @CraigJ, yes, `%Java_Home%` is an environmental variable that (should) be created when you install the JRE (or is it the JDK? Not sure). I remember people had problems with it not being set on olders JREs though. Any specific reason you are using 1.5.x instead of JRE6?